# python generating excel with panda

Tags: python

let me tell u my problem  in detail ... i have a loop which outputs me name of a person which got recognized if it is present in my database otherwise it will not be recognized , and if it got recognized a FOR loop will output me that name and then i want that name to be stored in excel sheet (i-e DATAFRAME) but it always store that name which FOR loop gives in the last iteration ,and all other names that it outputs in previous iterations will be lost , it definitely is doing over writing again and again  here is my complete code  , please answer it specifically

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import csv
import dlib
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from skimage import  io
import face_recognition
from PIL import Image
with open("Data/train.csv","r") as facefeatures2:
    reader=csv.reader(facefeatures2)
    featureslist2=[]
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) != 0:
            featureslist2= featureslist2 +[row]

facefeatures2.close()
float_int2=[]
results=[]
for f2 in range(0,len(featureslist2)):
    float_int2 = float_int2 +[[float(str) for str in subarray] for subarray in [featureslist2[f2]]]
    csv2 = np.vstack(float_int2)
faces_folder_path = "Data/newcropped"
list = os.listdir(faces_folder_path) # dir is your directory path
number_files = len(list)
print (number_files)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_name11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for loop in range(0,number_files):
    print("iteration ="+str(loop+1))
    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(faces_folder_path + "/" + str(loop+1)+".jpg")
    cv2.imshow("test",unknown_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    #### --------------exception handling-----------####
    try:
        unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

    except  IndexError:
        print("--->image is not detectable")
        pass
        # ...........................#
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces(csv2, unknown_face_encoding)
    chunks=[results[x:x + 12] for x in range(0, len(results),12)] # splits "results" list into sublists of size 12
    dirpath = "Data/eachperson"
    fname = []
    fname = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir(dirpath))]
    counter = 0
    index=0
    for c in range (0,len(chunks)):
        if 'True' in str(chunks[c]):
            counter=counter+1
            index=c
            df = pd.DataFrame({'names': [fname[index]]})
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    if counter !=1 or counter ==0 :
           print("student is not present :(")
    else:
        print(str(fname[index])+" is present!!!")
writer.save()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update SQL output data into Existing Excel in respective sheet using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674596/update-sql-output-data-into-existing-excel-in-respective-sheet-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question with an answer that will solve your problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674596/update-sql-output-data-into-existing-excel-in-respective-sheet-using-python/45675354#45675354).

Edit: I will try to extend my answer without being able to test your code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': [fname[index]]})
```

overwrites the dataframe in each loop.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

stores the dataframe to be written to Excel on sheet one. In the next iteration you overwrite this information. Pandas' to_excel() function is not appending.

You could try to store all the names in a list first, convert to a dataframe and then to_excel().

```
names_present = []
for loop in range(0,number_files):
    print("iteration ="+str(loop+1))
    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(faces_folder_path + "/" + str(loop+1)+".jpg")
    cv2.imshow("test",unknown_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    #### --------------exception handling-----------####
    try:
        unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

    except  IndexError:
        print("--->image is not detectable")
        pass
        # ...........................#
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces(csv2, unknown_face_encoding)
    chunks=[results[x:x + 12] for x in range(0, len(results),12)] # splits "results" list into sublists of size 12
    dirpath = "Data/eachperson"
    fname = []
    fname = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir(dirpath))]
    counter = 0
    index=0
    for c in range (0,len(chunks)):
        if 'True' in str(chunks[c]):
            counter=counter+1
            index=c
    if counter !=1 or counter ==0 :
           print("student is not present :(")
    else:
        print(str(fname[index])+" is present!!!")
        # Store all names present in list
        names_present.append(str(fname[index])
# Convert list to dataframe and safe
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_name11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': names_present})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: silvanoe please answer now to my edited version thank you